# Getting Error While compiling a Socket C program for HTTPS(OPENSSL) using gcc

Tags: c, gcc, cmake, compiler-errors, openssl

I am preparing a socket C program using OpenSSL package on Ubuntu 18. When I am trying to compile the program using the following command:

```
gcc WinSocketClientSSL.c -o WinSocketClientSSL -lssl
```

I am getting the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccfr2z39.o: undefined reference to symbol 'OPENSSL_init_crypto@@OPENSSL_1_1_0'
/usr/bin/ld: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have already tried using target_link_libraries() as my libssl.a and libcrypto.a files are in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ folder. Following is my entry:

```
add_executable(Win_Socket_Client_SSL src/WinSocketClientSSL.c)
target_link_libraries(WinSocketClientSSL /usr/libx86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.a)
target_link_libraries(WinSocketClientSSL /usr/libx86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.a)
```

Comment: Forgot `-lcrypto`: `gcc WinSocketClientSSL.c -o WinSocketClientSSL -lssl -lcrypto`